# I'm trying to go from the soon to be deprecated mysql statements to msqli prepared statements, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Here's my PHP:

```
    $db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Could not connect to database.";
    }

    // On first connect to database, create a user to hold data for users not logged in
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i" , 1);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("isss", 1, "anonymous", "anonymous", password_hash("noidentity", PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

But when it runs, I get this error:

Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

And it points to the line that I have `$stmt->bind_param("i" , 1);`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Also, if I want to set the value of a field in a row to 1 higher than it currently is, how do I do that with prepared statements?

This, for example: `UPDATE users SET wins = wins + 1 WHERE id = ?` Setting wins to something is a value, so I assume it should be used with a prepared statement, but do I consider "wins + 1" to be a string, and include that in a prepared statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All arguments to `bind_param` (except the first) must be variables passed by reference, you can't just pass literal values such as `1`, `"anonymous"`...

If the values to be inserted are fixed like these, there is no point in using `bind_param` at all, as it is completely safe to just have them in the query:

```
$stmt = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password) VALUES (1, 'anonymous',...)");
```

However in general you will need to put these parameters into variables, such as:

```
$params = Array(1,"anonymous","anonymous",password_hash("noidentity",PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
$stmt->bind_param("isss",$params[0],$params[1],$params[2],$params[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$param = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("i" , $param);
```

Because you cannot pass a value in the bind, only a parameter.

Comment: This question has an answer already. What's the point in adding another?

Comment: not adding another. check the date. just update the formatting a little.

Answer (score 0):

This is why I prefer PDO over Mysqli.

In PDO, you don't need to bind anything, you just pass values to `execute()` and you can pass them by value so you can use literals and expressions.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?");

$status = $stmt->execute(array(1, "anonymous", "anonymous", 
    password_hash("noidentity", PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

Of course check for success after each prepare() and execute().

Comment: (I'm making this a CW post since this is basically a comment but won't fit in a comment.)

Answer (score -1):

This block of code is logically flawed:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Could not connect to database.";
}
```

In the case that there *was not* an error this function will return `0` aka `false`, not to mention that this does not cause the script to exit or otherwise skip the query execution. You should change it to something like:

```
$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database)
if( $db->connect_error ) {
    echo "Could not connect to database.\n" .
        "Err: " . $db->connect_errno() . "\n" . $db->connect_error();
    // die/exit/return error/throw exception, or...
} else {
    // query prep/execution here
}
```

You're also mixing OO and procedural calls, I don't know if that's significant or not execution-wise, but it's confusing.

Comment: In some older versions of PHP, you need to use `mysqli_connect_error()` in the procedural form because `new mysqli()` isn't guaranteed to return an object when the connect fails.  Calling `false->connect_error()` would be a fatal mistake.

Comment: Thanks. Also, it's `$db -> connect_err` without the parantheses.

Comment: @BillKarwin I originally had the `$db = new...` bit in the `if` condition, but the PHP docs are not clear on what is assigned to `$db` if the constructor fails. My assumption is that an exception would be thrown if the constructor fails, and some Object otherwise.

Comment: @Sammitch, it's easy to test, just misspell your hostname or username and see what happens.  FWIW, what happens depends on your version of PHP.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.